# ¿Qué significa el sufijo "-únculo"?

Tags: significado, sufijos

Existen en español palabras que acaban con el sufijo *-únculo*:

- [**Forúnculo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IHdMqdL). Inflamación purulenta producida por la infección bacteriana de un folículo piloso.
- [**Homúnculo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KcFjeMR). Hombre pequeño.
- [**Ranúnculo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V8DBMFn). Planta herbácea anual, de la familia de las ranunculáceas, venenosa, común en terrenos húmedos, de flores generalmente amarillas o blancas, y de la que existen varias especies.
- [**Pedúnculo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKHBrlj). Prolongación del cuerpo, mediante la cual están fijos al suelo algunos animales de vida sedentaria, como los percebes.

En el DRAE se pueden consultar prefijos y sufijos, pero *-únculo* no viene recogido. Así que imagino que será una forma de construir palabras que viene del latín (todas las palabras mencionadas vienen directamente del latín), posiblemente con el significado de "pequeño" (ya que *homúnculo* es un hombre pequeño). ¿Es así? Pero entonces, ¿un *forúnculo* qué es etimológicamente hablando? ¿Un *qué* pequeño?

Bonus: ¿existen más palabras en español con esta terminación?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El DRAE no refleja la etimología, pero buscando en inglés el Online Etymology Dictionary da algunas pistas:

> [**homunculus**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=homunculus&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) [Look up homunculus at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/homunculus)
>   "tiny human being produced artificially," 1650s, from Latin homunculus (plural homunculi), literally "little person," **with -culus, diminutive suffix**, + homo (genitive hominis), which technically meant "male human," but it also was used with a sense "the human race, mankind;" while in Vulgar Latin it could be used as "one, anyone, they, people" and in logical and scholastic writing as "a human being, person." This is conjectured to be perhaps from PIE *(dh)ghomon-, literally "earthling," from *dhghem- "earth" (see chthonic; also compare human). Other Latin diminutives from homo included homullus, homuncio.

El enlace a Dictionary.com nos lleva a:

> [*homunculus*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/homunculus)
>    1650-60; < Latin, equivalent to homun- (variant of homin-, stem of homō man; see Homo ) + -culus [-cule<sup>1</sup>](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-cule)

Siguiendo el último enlace llegamos a:

> -cule
>   1. variant of [-cle<sup>1</sup>](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-cle):
>   animalcule; molecule; reticule.

Lo que nos lleva a la referencia final, la útil:

> -cle<sup>1</sup>
>   Word Origin
>   1. a suffix found in French loanwords of Latin origin, originally diminutive nouns, and later in adaptations of words borrowed directly from Latin or in Neo-Latin coinages:
>   article; conventicle; corpuscle; particle.

Es decir, que se trata de un sufijo usado como diminutivo, usado especialmente para las palabras inventadas (*coinages*) en Neolatín.

Esto lo refleja también Online Etymology Dictionary en su entrada de [*-cule*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-cule&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **word-forming element used to make diminutives**, from French -cule or directly from Latin -culus (masc.), -cula (fem.), -culum (neuter); these appear to be variants of the diminutive suffix -ulus (see -ule) used after -i-, -e-, -u-, and consonant stems [Gildersleeve], or might be a double-diminutive involving "an ancient diminutive suffix *-qo-" [Palmer, "The Latin Language"].

De todas las palabras que indicas, este sufijo diminutivo encaja con *forúnculo*, *homúnculo* y [*pedúnculo*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peduncle&allowed_in_frame=0). Sin embargo, ranúnculo parece que no, ¿verdad? Pues sí, ¡también! [Dictionary.com nos indica](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ranunculus?s=t) que viene de renacuajo, es decir rana pequeña. Así que confirmaría el uso de este diminutivo en los cuatro ejemplos que presentas.

---

> Pero entonces, ¿un *forúnculo* qué es etimológicamente hablando? ¿Un *qué* pequeño?

Tal y como tú mismo [descubriste](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17817/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-sufijo-%C3%BAnculo#comment25738_17818):

> [forúnculo](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=furuncle) viene de fur, furis (ladrón), teniendo por tanto la misma raíz que furtivo. Significaría "pequeño ladrón"

---

> Bonus: ¿existen más palabras en español con esta terminación?

Quise utilizar el [diccionario inverso](http://www.dirae.es) dirae.es para encontrar otras palabras con esta terminación. Sin embargo, parece que el buscador está caído.

Pero [rsanchez nos descubrió el otro día](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17787/1674) un truco muy majo para encontrar palabras, así que le pregunté a google `culo site:dirae.es` y encontré algunas cosas. Sin embargo, al no ser palabras completas tampoco fue de mucha utilidad.

Finalmente, di con un fichero que tienen por ahí llamado [lemario-inverso-20110518.txt](http://dirae.es/static/lemario-inverso-20110518.txt) donde encontré las siguientes palabras terminadas en *-culo*, para alguna de las cuales busqué su entrada en el DRAE. En la mayoría de casos encaja con el sentido de diminutivo:

culo
[báculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4lGM378)
caculo
[jáculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MI5zopY)
[cenáculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8By1G2O)
tenáculo
[signáculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xr5EMax)
[propugnáculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UOzHzWG) (esta no parece compartir etimología de diminutivo)
[pináculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T1yt7JD) (tampoco)
tabernáculo
infernáculo
vernáculo
invernáculo
tapaculo
umbráculo
espiráculo
oráculo
arrastraculo
espectáculo
habitáculo
tentáculo
sustentáculo
receptáculo
obstáculo
lambeculo
espéculo
reculo
cubículo
fascículo
edículo
pedículo
ridículo
ofendículo
perpendículo
vehículo
calículo
folículo
caulículo
panículo
adminículo
funículo
apículo
currículo
ventrículo
sículo
versículo
baticulo
retículo
dentículo
conventículo
fontículo
montículo
artículo
divertículo
testículo
cálculo
animálculo
ardínculo
vínculo
carbúnculo
pedúnculo
homúnculo
ranúnculo
forúnculo
furúnculo
fóculo
flóculo
inóculo
binóculo
monóculo
póculo
tubérculo
opérculo
círculo
semicírculo
tórculo
súrculo
másculo
ósculo
flósculo
semiflósculo
músculo
minúsculo
munúsculo
crepúsculo
[opúsculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R80nyu8)
corpúsculo
[grupúsculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JatIfoa)
mayúsculo
dilúculo

Comment: ¡Genial la respuesta! Me llama mucho la atención que palabras como _molécula_ y _retícula_ estén formadas usando el mismo sufijo diminutivo (una mole pequeña y una red pequeña).

Comment: En el diccionario etimológico que mencionas dice que _forúnculo_ viene de _fur, furis_ (ladrón), teniendo por tanto la misma raíz que _furtivo_. Significaría "pequeño ladrón".

Comment: Otra palabra es *carbúnculo* (rubí); igualmente, de *pequeño carbón (encendido)*. O *ridículo* (de *ridere*, reír). Pero no veo ninguna palabra que haya recibido el sufijo en castellano, todas ellas lo tenían ya en latín. En algún caso, sin la c (*ménsula*).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo salen palabras la mar de bonitas, como _grupúsculo_, _opúsculo_ o _montículo_. Luego hay otras que no son, como _músculo_. En cualquier caso, ¡gran descubrimiento el de _-culo_!

Comment: @fedorqui *Músculo* es, etimológicamente, un ratón (en latín, *mus*) pequeño. A alguien se le ocurrió que el bulto formado por el bíceps al contraerse se parecía a un ratoncillo.