# What are some extended or augmented words or phrases?

Tags: coloquialismos

Inspired by [What are some of the most useful shortened Spanish words for someone learning Spanish to know?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17782/9385), what are some extended or augmented words or phrases?

I know one but I wonder if there are more.

Answer (score 2):

In place of **para mí**: **para Miguelito.**  Example:

> Carmela me hizo la cena para Miguelito. | Carmela made dinner just for me.

Comment: @walen - That's fine with me.  Would you like to do the restructuring?

Answer (score 1):

Ahorita is a very common example. It's ironic that it can mean "right now" or "in a little bit".